# Deployment of Razor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I find 2 issues deploying Razor page projects(perhaps in other .net core project also):

1. When I deploy the main compilied release file myprojectname.dll, I need to stop the website in IIS or I will fail because the file is using.  How if I don't have control of IIS in the hosting environment?
2. I have to re-deploy the file myprojectname.dll even changing a single word in the textual content.  Is there any simple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I deploy the main compilied release file myprojectname.dll, I need to stop the website in IIS or I will fail because the file is using. How if I don't have control of IIS in the hosting environment?

The solutions is you should firstly put a `app_offline.htm` file inside your IIS folder to stop the whole application, then after deploy remove the  `app_offline.htm` to start the application. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Besides, without any permission to control the IIS, you also couldn't publish and running the application on that server.

> I have to re-deploy the file myprojectname.dll even changing a single word in the textual content. Is there any simple method?

If you are using the web deploy inside the visual studio to publish the web application, it will firstly check what the file you have changed, it will only publish the file which you have changed. But if you compilied all the file into a single file, it have to build again and publish all the files to the remote folder.